# Should an ERP contain documents

Tags: meta, erp, dms

> Should an ERP contain documents?

Option 1: Store documents in ERP database

*Pros:*

- integrated system
- easier document **generation** and direct storing in database by ERP
- Integrated access management for documents

*Cons:*

- Explosive growth of database, especially for large files, autocad drawings, ...
- Longer backup and restore time
- ERP needs to expose API for other LOB applications that want to create/store documents

Option 2: separate document management system and ERP. This might be a simple filestorage or a sharepoint, ...

*Pros:*

- If DMS crashes, ERP stays online
- Faster performance for core ERP functionality
- Easier access to documents for other applications
- Potentially faster storing and retrieving of documents, because this is the core functionality of the DMS

*Cons:*

- No integration, maintaining of 2 systems
- No access control, or **double implementation** of access control (once for ERP and once for DMS)

=> I am talking about **large** erp systems, containing many and large documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer it to be separated. ERP only contains the link path, but the real file is in the DMS. Because of the natural objective for ERP to make decision and manipulate data, and generate the file as a result.eg:invoicing, report.

I also use ERP system as my business control panel, that generates the files, later when I need that file I search from my ERP, and get it only from the link.

ERP only to look at the summary. When certain transactions need to be reviewed, then I open the file.

Answer (score 1):

"No integration" is not quite right.
This point depends on your ERP system and your DMS system
Our ERP system supports many DMS systems. Some of them even have full integration (bidirectional)

Answer (score 1):

### NO.

Its better to be separated than its both together. It will be easier to access the file whenever we want. The other [ERP Software](http://mindsoftglobal.com/) we use has same system like this.